# Repeat string with integer multiplication

Tags: rust

Is there an easy way to do the following (from Python) in Rust?

`>>> print ("Repeat" * 4)
RepeatRepeatRepeatRepeat`

I'm starting to learn the language, and it seems `String` doesn't override `Mul`, and I can't find any discussion anywhere on a compact way of doing this (other than a map or loop).

Answer (score 141, accepted):

#### Rust 1.16+

[`str::repeat`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.repeat) is now available:

```
fn main() {
    let repeated = "Repeat".repeat(4);
    println!("{}", repeated);
}
```

#### Rust 1.0+

You can use [`iter::repeat`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/fn.repeat.html):

```
use std::iter;

fn main() {
    let repeated: String = iter::repeat("Repeat").take(4).collect();
    println!("{}", repeated);
}
```

This also has the benefit of being more generic — it creates an infinitely repeating iterator of any type that is cloneable.

Comment: I love the rust 16 way!

Comment: 1.16 is as clean as it gets

Answer (score 5):

This one doesn't use `Iterator::map` but `Iterator::fold` instead:

```
fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", (1..5).fold(String::new(), |b, _| b + "Repeat"));
}
```

Comment: That's neat, too, thanks! (though I'd say a bit less readable than the iterator one.)