# Is repeat(x).take(n) performant?

Tags: performance, rust

I'm looking for an efficient way to write the following function, as discussed in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31216646/repeat-string-with-integer-multiplication/31216683#31216683):

```
fn dots(n: usize) -> String {
    std::iter::repeat('.').take(n).collect()
}
```

Does Rust generate concrete types for instances of generic struct types? Is the result of `repeat('.').take(n)` (the struct `Take<Repeat<char>>`) equivalent to

```
struct Take_Repeat_char {
    element: char,
    n: usize
}
```

Are method implementations inlined - will there be a version of `Take::next()` that has `Repeat::next()` inlined in it?

What is a good way to check this for myself? Inspecting LLVM IR?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, this is Rusty™ enough. And yes, LLVM will inline the whole thing if you compile with optimizations (e.g. `cargo build --release`). Check via [play.rust-lang.org](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=39767c6e6ca4f217e68c&version=stable) and look at the generated assembly. The code in question is:

```
movb    $46, (%rax)
movb    $46, 1(%rax)
movb    $46, 2(%rax)
movb    $46, 3(%rax)
movb    $46, 4(%rax)
```

for five dots. I believe it might be possible to go faster by merging the first four dots into one

```
movd    $x2e2e2e2e, (%rax)
```

instruction, but I don't think it will make much of a difference. Edit: Actually depending on memory alignment, it may be faster *or* slower: if `%rax` is aligned, it could probably be a bit faster (depending on complex things like caches, prefetching, etc.), otherwise it will probably be slower (because of possible traps).

Comment: I had to -1 since it's simply not performant enough. We cannot flatly repeat the line "iterator inline great" (which they do) to motivate conclusions like "it optimizes to good code" which are not true.

Comment: Relevant rust PR that improved `BufWriter` construction: [see this diff hunk](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/26849/files#diff-a074b6c6ae44d9ac353aa145411afb53L65)

Comment: @bluss: fair enough – please note that I did not say this'll work in all circumstances, just for the specific example given.

Comment: True. The inlined `dots(5)` looks fine, you made an example that's nice and I answered with another that's not as great. I think it's important to say that `repeat().take()` doesn't always result in the best code. We could say the “sufficiently good compiler” hasn't yet arrived.

Answer (score 8):

> Does Rust generate concrete types for instances of generic struct types?

Yes, this is called *monomorphization*.

> Are method implementations inlined?

Like many languages, this is a solid "maybe". There are [hints you can provide the compiler](http://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#inline-attributes) to control inlining both inter- and intra-crate, but it's usually up to the compiler to Do The Right Thing. As above, if a function uses a generic type, it's automatically available for monomorphization, which means that information needed to inline it is available in a compiled crate.

> What is a good way to check this for myself?

Many people will use the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/) to view the LLVM IR or assembly. Of course, you can view that locally with `rustc --emit [asm|llvm-ir]`. When doing this, I put the code I'm interested in a function that will never be inlined. That makes it much easier to find in the assembly / IR output:

```
#[inline(never)]
fn dots(n: usize) -> String {
    std::iter::repeat('.').take(n).collect()
}
```

As [llogiq](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32922283/155423) has already pointed out, rustc and LLVM already see through your entire implementation and have unrolled it completely. The implementation changes based on how many characters you want though.

The **only** way to know if it is fast is to profile. Quoting llogiq:

> I believe it might be possible to go faster by merging the first four dots into one `movd`

I'd advocate testing any such code in The Real World. Assembly is non-trivial, especially the x64 / x86_64 variants. Instructions may have strange pipeline requirements or may cause other parts of the CPU to be unavailable.

Profile, profile, profile! ^_^

Answer (score 6):

It's not really performant, it's kind of bad.

```
const CAP: usize = 64 * 1024;

#[bench]
fn fill_string_repeat(b: &mut Bencher) {
    b.iter(|| {
        repeat('.').take(CAP).collect::<String>()
    });
    b.bytes = CAP as u64;
}

#[bench]
fn fill_string_vec(b: &mut Bencher) {
    b.iter(|| {
        String::from_utf8(vec![b'.'; CAP])
    });
    b.bytes = CAP as u64;
}
```

Result:

```
test fill_string_repeat              ... bench:     240,467 ns/iter (+/- 719) = 272 MB/s
test fill_string_vec                 ... bench:     106,885 ns/iter (+/- 224) = 613 MB/s
```

The `vec!` solution is much better, and that is including the UTF-8 checking overhead, which dominates, use `String::from_utf8_unchecked` and get:

```
test fill_string_vec_unchecked       ... bench:      29,354 ns/iter (+/- 503) = 2232 MB/s
```

(Here basically just the memset remains.)

Comment: Built in release mode?