# Initialize array of array of strings in GoLang and Rust

Tags: arrays, go, rust

I want to initialize a 2D array in which each member of inner array holds a string of 1000 x's. Something like:

```
var data = [num_rows][num_cols]string("x....x(upto 1000)")
```

But all google searches have been futile. In C++ I can achieve similar thing like this:

```
vector<vector<string>> data(num_rows, vector<string>(num_cols, string("x",1000)));
```

And in Ruby something like this:

```
Array.new(num_rows) { Array.new(num_cols) { "x"*1000 } }
```

Want to achieve similar result in go but I am unable to find any documentation to fill a string and initialize a 2D array. Also note that I want to generate the string for each member of array rather than using an available string.

PS : I am also looking for something similar in Rust

Comment: `a := []string{'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx'}`?

Comment: @u_mulder So this is an array of 3 "xxx". Say I want to initialize it to thousand "x...1000x here". How do I achieve that like string constructor of c++?

Comment: `strings.Repeat("x", 1000)`?

Comment: @u_mulder Awesome! Any idea about how to initialize a slice or an array of 1000 elems with this string(I mean is there a library function for that or do I have to use iteration myself?)

Comment: It would be clearer if the Go and Rust questions were separate. As it is, how are you going to accept a best answer? Please split this question in two and cross-reference them.

Comment: Initialize a 2D array of strings `a:= [][]string{{""}, {""}}`

Answer (score 2):

In Rust, it depends on what you want to use these values for. I like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31216683/2075745) for creating the repeated string. The "rows" depend on if you want reference or copy semantics which is made explicit in rust. The `borrows` vector is a bunch of borrowed strings that refer back to the memory owned by `x_s`. The `copies` vector is a bunch of in memory copies of the original `x_s` string.

```
use std::iter;

fn main() {
    let num_rows = 1000;
    let num_cols = 1000; 

    let x_s : String = iter::repeat('x').take(num_cols).collect();

    // pick one of the below
    let borrows : Vec<&str> = vec![&*x_s ; num_rows];
    let copies : Vec<String> = vec![x_s.clone() ; num_rows];
}
```

The call to `clone` in the last line is because the `vec` macro moves the value sent into it. The `vec` macro will also clone this clone `num_rows` times in the case of the `copies`. Note that this `clone` is probably not necessary in most use cases as you would not normally have `borrows` and `copies` in the same scope at the same time.

As a caveat, I am fairly new to rust but believe this to be a decent answer. I am happy to accept corrections.

Comment: Whether the element type is `&str` or `String`, you can construct the Vec with `vec![elem; n]`.

Comment: I agree that the `borrows` can be converted to this syntax but due to calling clone, I don't think that the `copies` can be converted to this syntax.

Comment: `vec![x; n]` calls `clone`: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e47235e5242cb81537e2ee1a5677a071&version=stable&backtrace=0

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I updated the post to reflect them. How does this look? More canonical now I suppose?

Comment: For copies, just `vec![x_s; num_rows]` is sufficient. Otherwise it looks good!

Comment: This doesn't work due to moving `x_s` which is borrowed in the previous line. I think it boils down to the fact that [this function](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/ab7c35fa0fcd725cdc207487b760d85fd07ecdd7/src/libcollections/vec.rs#L1112) moves its argument `elem`

Comment: Oh, right, sorry. However, in real code one probably wouldn't have both `borrows` and `copies`, so then it would work.

Answer (score 1):

you could use slices. this may not be the shortest solution, but it works for me.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    xs := strings.Repeat("x", 1000)

    num_rows := 5
    num_cols := 5

    data := make([][]string, num_rows)
    for y := 0; y < num_rows; y++ {
        data[y] = make([]string, num_cols)
        for x := 0; x < num_cols; x++ {
            data[y][x] = xs
        }
    }

    fmt.Printf("%T", data)
    fmt.Print(data)
}
```

Comment: quite close. Is there not a 1 liner?

Answer (score 0):

A very simple on-line exemple in rust :

```
fn main() {
    let data: Vec<String> = (0..1000).map(|n| (0..n).map(|_| 'x').collect()).collect();
    println!("{:?}", data);
}
```

Comment: @icza From the question: "PS : I am also looking for something similar in Rust" --- admittedly, that's not good style for a question.

Comment: @delnan I think that would be marked as duplicate. No?

Comment: @sky_coder123: No; different languages do things differently, so the questions are different by virtue of asking for different situations.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I am actually trying to assess performance of various languages for some operations so I thought these would be related. I agree there would be different ways to do different things(just like Ruby and C++ supplied in question) but then my intention was not to ask about only one particular language.

Comment: @sky_coder123: Have you looked at [The Computer Language Benchmark](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/)? Roughly speaking, C/C++/Rust are in the same ballpark, Go is slightly slower (within Java ballpark, not much more than x1.5/x2 in general) and Ruby is of course much slower (x10/x50). And of course, you should take micro-benchmarks with a grain of salt, especially when interpreted languages delegate the bulk of the computation to a C library...

Comment: Yeah I've looked at it but there was a fun discussion about these at my workplace. I found Go to be performing faster than C/C++ though for a very naive benchmark. What my interest was if there is a language that can perform faster than Ruby for some tasks in our project.